# Using Django to summarize Report

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to produce a table that will show the total maturity amounts for each financial institution that a plan has.

A plan is the term I use for person.  So each person can have multiple investments.  I'm having trouble creating a table that will do this correctly.

Currently I have a report that displays each investment sorted by Maturity Date, i.e. 2011,2012, etc.

At the bottom I would like to place this summary table, but my query displays duplicates of each financial institution, due to being able to have multiple investments.

My current query:

```
list = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = plan).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__gte= '%s-1-1' % current_year).distinct()
```

This will output:

- TD Bank      $10k
- TD Bank      $10k
- Scotia Bank  $10k
- Etc

But I'd like:

- TD Bank     $20k
- Scotia Bank $10k
- Etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you want to aggregate the values of the investments for a plan:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
my_plan.investment_set.filter(
    maturity_date__gte=whenever
).values('financial_institution').annotate(Sum('value'))
```