# Looping through annotate query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Initially I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600431/using-django-to-summarize-report), and I wanted to give credit to Daniel.  Here is the new issue I have however.

I have this which works great, but I'm having a minor issue.

```
total_list = plan.investment_set.filter(maturity_date__gte= '%s-1-1' % current_year).values('financial_institution').annotate(Sum('maturity_amount'))
```

I'm having trouble displaying the financial institution name.  When I loop through total list and put loop_variable.financial_institution it shows me the ID but not the name.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the "financial_institution" model has a `name` field, I think you could just add it to the list of values you're asking for:

```
total_list = plan.investment_set.filter(
    maturity_date__gte= '%s-1-1' % current_year
).values(
    'financial_institution',
    'financial_institution__name'
).annotate(Sum('maturity_amount'))
```