# Calculating the sum of aggregate query set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I have a query set that returns a list of financial institutions and also the total amount of money in investments I have with each institution.

views.py

```
total_list = plan.investment_set.filter(maturity_date__gte= '%s-1-1' % current_year).values('financial_institution__abbr').annotate(Sum('maturity_amount'))
```

What I would like to do now, is find a grand total for all that money.  My question is, how do I go about calculating the sum to find the total of all my investments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
total_list = plan.investment_set.filter(
    maturity_date__gte= '%s-1-1' % current_year
).aggregate(Sum('maturity_amount'))
```

which should give you:

```
{'maturity_amount__sum': <total amount>}
```

Comment: Yes, this is right. The point is, you can't do it in the same query as the original aggregation - you need one to get the subtotal, and one for the grand total.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Yes, I think that's correct. Although I think that even if you could chain on the existing queryset, you'd still be making an extra database call - so the difference would be slightly simpler code, not better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is creating a hassle. Is the field that you're calculating maturity_amount named value? If so, you may try this which worked for your previous question ([Using Django to summarize Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600431/using-django-to-summarize-report)):

```
grand_total = plan.investment_set.annotate(Sum('value'))
```